# Passing object to another class

Tags: c++

I am trying to pass an instance of an class to another class so that one can edit certain parts of it.

```
Class B{
    A *a;
    void foo(){
        a = new A(this);
        a->doSomething();
    }

Class A{
    B &b;
    A(B &b):b(b){

    }
    void doSomething(){
        //Does something to change b
    }
}
```

Unfortunatly it doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: Please study a introductory textbook. You have glaring, very basic syntax errors. Stack Overflow isn't the place for learning basic syntax.

Comment: What does "it doesn't seem to work" mean? Please provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It does compile now but it still crashes the arduino during the update.

Comment: From the seemingly intend `a = new A(this);` should be `a = new A(*this);` Try [this concept](http://ideone.com/Lx9y8O).

Comment: Also people are quite hostile to a simple question it seems.

Comment: @user3710529 The code you posted here is bogus! Unless you're showing what you really have or which compiler errors you need to fix, your quesiton is doomed. Nothing about _hostility_ (check the tooltip text appearing if you hover your mouse pointer over the downvote button), just improve your question. There's plenty of [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) available how to do so, especially the requirement of providing a [MCVE] as already mentioned.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

People are not being hostile, they just want you to try.

I wont give you the answer but there are many help out there on learning about classes.

Take at look at both of your classes. Do you see any errors? I just added hint so you can see some errors.

```
Class B{
    A *a;
    //hint private? or public?
    void foo(){
        a = new A(this);
        a->doSomething();
    }

Class A{
    B &b;
    //hint
    A(B &b):b(b){  //hint

    }
    void doSomething(){
        //Does something to change b
        //so show us
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed a bunch of more hints, this doesn't answer the _"question"_.

Comment: Already found the answer. Reason why I was having trouble was that I am programming on an arduino which don't give that much information when you go out of bounds on an index (they just crash). Thought I made a mistake on the described part as passing pointers and references is a point I am extremely weak at.

Comment: @user3710529 Doesn't seem to be an arduino specific problem actually. You didn't provide the right minimal code sample, thus you couldn't expect getting concise solution from here. Remember when asking next time if you plan to do so.

Comment: Thought that the code I provided was wrong (which it was but that happened after me tinkering at it for 2 hours). Solution was something I should have seen at the start but had classic case of tunnel vision (fixable by using a serial monitor and adding prints everywhere).

Comment: @user3710529 And how do you think this Q&A pair now helps anyone in future research to solve a problem that's similar to yours? Read it all over again from that POV please!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that was the whole point. I wasnt giving him the answer. I was providing a little guide, nothing more. It was so he a better chance of fixing it by knowing the very small mistakes he is making. He did manage to find the solution though.

Comment: @SA That's though not helpful for the general purpose of the site to create a Q&A repository that can be researched in future, The actual solution is just hidden, everything is still left unclear.